# Linked List of Strings

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I'm trying to make a `StringBuilder` like class using linked lists, and I think I'm messing up somewhere in my constructor.  Can anyone find an issue here?  I believe the issue is with how I'm moving to the next node.

Node class:

```
private class CNode
{
    private char data;
    private CNode next;

    private CNode(char c)
    {
        data = c;
        next = null;
    }

    private CNode(char c, CNode nextNode)
    {
        data = c;
        next = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Constructor:

```
private CNode firstNode;
private int length;

public MyString(String s)
{
    if(s == null)
    {
        this.length = 0;
        this.firstNode = null;
    }
    else if(s.length() == 1)
    {
        this.length = 1;
        this.firstNode.data = s.charAt(0);
        this.firstNode.next = null;
    }
    else
    {
        this.length = s.length();
        CNode node = null;
        CNode nextNode = null;

        this.firstNode = new CNode(s.charAt(0), node);

        for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            node = new CNode(s.charAt(i), nextNode);
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is at

```
this.firstNode = new CNode(s.charAt(0), node);
```

When that line executes, `node` is null, so your `firstNode` ends up linked to nothing. Further, in the for loop where you're trying to build the links, you never assign `nextNode`, but you try to use it to link one node to the next. Therefore, all the nodes end up linking to `null`, the initial value of `nextNode`.

Another issue:

```
this.firstNode.data = s.charAt(0);
this.firstNode.next = null;
```

That should be creating a new CNode instead because `this.firstNode` is still null when that code executes, which will cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: Isn't that the intent, though? It seems like the linked list of characters is stored in reverse order, so the first character shouldn't point at anything. (Unless that's *not* the intent, in which case that's definitely a problem!)

Comment: but I continue to set node in the following for loop?  doesn't that fix that problem?

Comment: @templatetypedef reverse order?  definitely not the intent.  how do you figure?

Comment: @templatetypedef: That's not how a linked list works, and it's not how he's building the links in the loop (or at least trying to).

Comment: @Nealon: See my updated answer. I've pointed out a couple more problems that I notice, including in some problems with your for loop.

Comment: @Nealon: A linked list is normally built by: 1) constructing a node with data; 2) if there's more data, constructing a second node, making this node the `next` of the node constructed in 1); 3) repeat until out of data. It's what you're sort of trying to do, but you're mixing things up.

Comment: right, but I'm having trouble implementing that for this case...  I've tried a couple different methods, and none i've come up with are significantly different.

Comment: The mistake you're consistently making is that you're trying to use a variable *before* you assign the appropriate value to it. You do that for both `node` and `nextNode` at the lines I pointed out in my answer. You need to make sure to create the appropriate `node` before using it, and the same for `nextNode`.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other issues here, but consider this block of code:

```
else if(s.length() == 1)
{
    this.length = 1;
    this.firstNode.data = s.charAt(0);
    this.firstNode.next = null;
}
```

Notice that you've never allocated `this.firstNode`, which means that you're going to get a `NullPointerException` when executing the second line of code. Try allocating a node before writing to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: replace the second two lines with `this.firstNode = new CNode(s.charAt(0), null);`?

Comment: @Nealon- That should definitely help!

Comment: excellent.  Still not fixed, but that solves other possible problems.  Thank you